# How to add "Order By" when loading a Magento Model

Tags: magento

I am trying to load a list of items from a Magento model. What I want to do is get the items in order by their created date so that I have the newest first.

Anyone know how I can do that?

Here is what I have so far:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('testimonials/testimonials')
  ->getCollection();
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was able to find the answer on my own.  This is what I had to do:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('testimonials/testimonials')
->getCollection()
->setOrder('created_time', 'DESC');
```

Comment: And setOrder is defined in app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php

Answer (score 1):

another method that can work too:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('package/module');

$model->getCollection()
      ->getSelect()->order();
```