# Magento product get attribute Need sort filter for descending order

Tags: php, sorting, magento

For this:

```
Mage::getModel ( 'eav/config' )->getAttribute ( 'catalog_product', 'brand' );
```

I need sort filter for descending order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add "Order By" when loading a Magento Model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158424/how-to-add-order-by-when-loading-a-magento-model)

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you'll need to do the following steps:

**1) Create an attribute**

- In admin-panel go to Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes and
  "Add New Attribute" (or edit the one you already have which you want
  to be sorted)
- For "brand" I would suggest "Dropdown" as "Catalog Input Type for
  Store Owner"
- Set "Used for Sorting in Product Listing" to "Yes"
- Create label and options as you desire, e.g. "Brands" as label,
  "nike", "Diesel" and "adidas" as options.

**2) Edit attribute set**

Go to Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attribute Sets and add your attribute to the attribute set you are using in your store.

**3) Edit Categories**

- Go to Catalog > Manage Categories
- Select the category in which the products should be sorted by brand.
- On the right hand side, change to tab "Display Settings". Here you
  see a list of all available "Sort By" options. (It's a
  multi-select-field, so you can select different attributes by holding
  CTRL.)

**4) Reindex Data**

Go to System > Index Management and re-index your data-tables

Given that "brands" are no numeric value, I don't get what you meant with "descending order". They will be sorted alphabetically.